# fstab entry causes emergency mode on reboot

Tags: centos, fedora, fstab

I am using a loop file system because I do not have another partition to mount and I am only practicing as I study for my sysadmin exam.  I added the following line to my stab

```
/tmp/imagefile        mnt/tempdir     ext4    defaults        0 0
```

— this was done after creating a 1 mb file using the dd command and successfully mounting it manually using the mount command.  However when I added this line to fstab and rebooted it restarted into emergency mode.  I was able to edit the file in emergency mode and removing the line allowed a normal reboot.  This happened on two systems a centos 7 system and a fedora 20 system.

Comment: Fixing the typo ought to help.

Comment: Placing a filesystem image in /tmp is not best practice, as the contents of /tmp may get automatically cleaned up. Then you would be stuck with a system that doesn't boot properly again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a loopback mount, you would want to invoke `mount` with `-o loop`, so change `defaults` to `loop`.

Also, give an absolute path to `/mnt/tempdir`.

After editing fstab, verify that you can run `mount /mnt/tempdir`, and if so, it should work on the next boot.

Comment: made changes, same result, looked at journalctl and noticed in could not find imagefile and noticed it was not there.  Maybe Fedora is removing it because it is in the tmp directory.

Comment: As mentioned in the comment, stuff in /tmp is assumed to be completely disposable. /var/tmp is for temporary stuff that requires persistence. But even using /var/tmp would be weird.